# Is there a way to make child element inherit parent class with Emmet BEM?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, parent-child, emmet, bem

So I have this problem where I create my parent object and a few child objects.

Using Emmets BEM funcitonality its easy `.parent-class>.-child-class` which yields the
`ParentClass="parent" ChildClass="parent__child"`. But if i then try to insert a new child object within the parent object using Emmet `.-new-child` only yields `__new-child`.

This initial block:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Should become this using Emmet `.-left+.-right`:

```
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__content">
    <div class="popup__left"></div>
    <div class="popup__right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make the child class inherit from the parent even after the initial creation? Or does it simply not understand what the actual top level parent is?

Comment: How should emmet know which class is the parent class, the BEM filter analyzes the expanded tree and modifies the class properties. there is no parent tag in this tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug in VSCode implementation, you should fill an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Your example works fine in Sublime Text plugin, Emmet actually analyses context HTML element to inherit block name